# get EXEC_BAD_ACCESS inside initWithCoder

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a problem during loading/creating a new view form xib file. I get EXEC_BAD_ACCESS code=2 and on my call stack i see multiple call of initWithCoder method. I do not understand why it is happened since i call alloc init for my class only once.
Below my code:

```
@interface SongListView :  NSView
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSScrollView* view;
@end

@implementation SongListView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];

    if(self)
    {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder: aDecoder];

    if(self)
    {
        [self setup];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setup
{
    NSArray *nib;

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"scrollTabViewItemWithTableView"
                                  owner:self
                        topLevelObjects:&nib];
    [self addSubview: self.view];
}

@end
```

and this is how I create SongListView:

```
SongListView* tableView = [[SongListView alloc] init];
```

Can someone explain me what happens, why i get mutiple call of initWithCoder method, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Generally your NSView subclasses shouldn’t load XIBs. They should either be IN a XIB (and thus created when the XIB loads) or created in code.

In your case there are a number of architecturally strange things, but I suspect the crash is caused by you having a `SongListView` instance inside scrollTabViewItemWithTableView.xib, so when you load the XIB you run setup and load the XIB and run setup and load the XIB and run setup and...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add your view as a subview of itself:

```
[self addSubview:self.view];
```

Code like this hurts my eyes. You have a `SongListView` object, but you've named it `tableView`. You've defined an initialiser for `initWithFrame:` but you are sending it the `init` message when you are creating it.

Comment: By itself, `-init` is fine, as it is an equivalent to `initWithFrame:` with `CGRectZero`. What's coming next is a mess, though.

Answer (score 0):

Loading nib causes a call to `-initWithCoder:` on the related class and passing `self` as owner assigns the top-level view in nib as self. You have a recursion because with each load, you try to load the view again.

Once you loaded the nib, in `-initWithCoder:` your view is already loaded, and you don't have to load nib or add subview.

What usually goes in `setup` are some UI additions, or some others things that couldn't be done in IB.

Comment: Having “self” as owner is generally fine. It’s how you hook up IBOutlets from and IBActions to “File’s Owner”.

Comment: @WilShipley isn't self in this case the mentioned File's Owner? Without this argument nib loader wouldn't know which instance to attach to.

Comment: Yes, that’s correct, but I don’t think the “initWithCoder:” is called because of this reference to self. Second paragraph points to the problem on its own, I think.

Comment: @WilShipley you're right, it isn't because of that. I rephrased to be a bit more clear on that, thank you.